# How to disable auto finishing brackets in .cl file with VS and Intel OpenCL SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a problem on VS with extensions of Intel OpenCL Code Builder. When I type the bracket like ( { [ in .cl files, It auto-completes this like () [] {} and the cursor points after these completed bracket.

It's really pain to me. May I get the solution of it? :)

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages. Automatic brace completion is checked or not?

Comment: @Jude Checked, but even without it, same result.

Comment: @user3498780 did you manage to find any solution? It's really annoying. So much, that I prefer to edit .cl in default editor.

Comment: Same problem, exactly.